Is World Region accessible for a search using Searchkit?
I want to add World Region as a filter in a FormBuilder search form, but I cannot locate the relevant field in SearchKit. It is clearly available in Civi as it is available in predefined Advanced Searches / Search Builder. I imagine I need to join a table in SearchKit to access it, but cannot see where?

You need to join to Countries and then world region is a field in there. If you've joined to Addresses then you can get it by joining Address to Address Countries.

Excellent - tested and functional! Thank you
